# Getting value from HTML form returns Null with REST

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest

I am not able to get data from html form to my java rest method as parameter.
Here's my html and angular code:

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("mycon",function($scope,$http){
    console.log("entered here1");
    $scope.test={};
    $scope.add = function() {
        console.log("entered here2");

    var json=JSON.stringify($scope.test);
    console.log($scope.test);
    console.log(json);

   $http.get("rest/xyz/role", 
           {
                data:json
           }
   ).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.data = data;
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("error");
    })





}});
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mycon">

<center>
<h2> Login Here! </h2>
<hr/>
    <form >

        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Signum Id:</td> 
            <td><input type="text" ng-model="test.sig"/></td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
      <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" ng-click="add()" name="action"> Submit <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </tr>
        </table>


    </form>
</center>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</body>
```

Rest code goes here:

```
@GET
@Path("/role")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
//@Consumes("text/plain")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public String list(String s) {
    System.out.print("Entered here ");

    System.out.print(s);

    return null;
}
```

I want signum field from form to pass as parameter in rest method.
    The output I am getting is null.

Comment: You `return null` in your backend function

Comment: What is the Output of conole.log Statements?

Answer (score 0):

Use http.post:

```
 $http.post("rest/xyz/role", {
                data:json
           } ...
```

Comment: If OP should use  `$http.post` he/she has also to Change the Annotation at backend side

Comment: Yes of course, because get request cannot take json data.

Comment: i am getting the json data now.But it is in string format,how do i access the sig field of that json data .

Comment: Use JSON.parse(). For example var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');

Comment: How to pass data from form to my rest service as a string. I want the value to be passed. String s is having json formatted data